# Указание пути до tesseract'а в программе

Tags: c++, распознавание, tesseract

Всех приветствую. Пытаюсь написать распознавалку текста на плюсах.

При запуске в консоле пишет такое сообщение:

> Error opening data file D:\c++
>   projects\vcpkg_test\x64\Release/tessdata/eng.traineddata Please make
>   sure the TESSDATA_PREFIX environment variable is set to your
>   "tessdata" directory. Failed loading language 'eng' Tesseract couldn't
>   load any languages!

Типа, не может найти trained-data языка.

Можно ли его указать путь до него в коде?

К примеру:

> D:\tessdata\eng.traineddata

Код:

```
#include <string>
#include <tesseract/baseapi.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    string outText;
    string imPath = "C:/Users/AndreyPC/Desktop/1.jpg";

    // Create Tesseract object
    tesseract::TessBaseAPI* ocr = new tesseract::TessBaseAPI();


    // Initialize tesseract to use English (eng) and the LSTM OCR engine. 
    ocr->Init(NULL, "eng", tesseract::OEM_LSTM_ONLY);

    // Set Page segmentation mode to PSM_AUTO (3)
    ocr->SetPageSegMode(tesseract::PSM_AUTO);

    // Open input image using OpenCV
    Mat im = cv::imread(imPath, IMREAD_COLOR);

    // Set image data
    ocr->SetImage(im.data, im.cols, im.rows, 3, im.step);

    // Run Tesseract OCR on image
    outText = string(ocr->GetUTF8Text());

    // print recognized text
    cout << outText << endl; // Destroy used object and release memory ocr->End();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: `1,jpg` выглядит подозрительно.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, упс, ошибка

Comment: "D:\c++ projects\vcpkg_test\x64\Release/tessdata/eng.traineddata" - что-то меня смущают слеши... особенно то, что они перемешаны